# How to display emps from a table?

Tags: oracle11g

I want to display all employees working from 01st april 1982 to till date from emp table.
How can i get those??

I tried this one but am not getting correct answer can any one help me
select * from emp where hiredate = '01-apr-1982';

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
//if you hiredate column is date format
select * from emp where hiredate > to_date('01-apr-1982','DD-mon-YYYY');
```